# Could not find JAXBContextFinder for media type: application/xml+fhir

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm writing a REST service to consume XML from a HL7 FHIR client.  The HL7 FHIR standard specifies the content type must be: application/xml+**fhir**.

Here is the code snippet:

```
@Path("/DecisionSupportServiceModule")
public class DSSModuleResource {

    private String namingProviderURL = null;
    private static final String OUTPUT_PARAMETERS1 = "outputParameters1";
    private final String CONSUMER_ID = "CONSUMER_ID";

    public DSSModuleResource() {
        namingProviderURL = FHIRMiscHelper.getNamingProviderURL();
    }

    @POST()
    @Path("/{id}/$evaluate")
    @Consumes("application/xml+fhir")
    @Produces("application/xml+fhir")
    public GuidanceResponse evaluate(@PathParam("id") String km_name,
        Parameters parameters) {
```

When I send a request to the service I get this error:

> 14:50:39,309 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] Failed executing POST /DecisionSupportServiceModule/CDCImmunizations/$evaluate: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: **Could not find JAXBContextFinder for media type: application/xml+fhir**

However when I change the code to use `Content-Type=application/xml` everything works as expected.

To try and solve this problem I implemented a custom MessageBodyReader/Writer to do marshal/unmarshal JAX-B messages back and forth to the client.  This also fails with the same error when using "application/xml+fhir".  So I'm stuck.  Has anyone seen this issue before and if so have a solution?  Thanks for your help.

My environment is as follows:

1. JBoss-6.1.0.Final
2. RESTEasy 2.2.1.GA
3. Java version: 1.6.0_38,Sun Microsystems Inc.

Comment: It should be `application/fhir+xml`. The `xml` needs to be at the end

Comment: This worked.  Thanks!